# wcag compliance issue with play/pause button

Tags: accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

As part of making our site WCAG compliance we are adding play/pause buttons for carousel.Here the screen reader is reading in different manner

```
<div id="imageCarouselPlayBtn" class="cblt-button imageCarouselPlayBtn" tabindex ="0">
    &#9658;
</div>
<div id="imageCarouselPauseBtn" class="cblt-button imageCarouselPauseBtn" tabindex ="0">
    &#8214;
</div>`
```

in this case screen reader is reading pause button as ***double vertical line*** and ***group*** for play button.
if we use sprite image instead it is reading as ***group*** for both play/pause buttons.
Is there any good solution for this problem instead of using image tags for both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use WAI-ARIA’s [`aria-label` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label):

> It provides the user with a recognizable name of the object.

Also: Is there a reason why you don’t use `button`/`input` instead of `div` for the play/pause *buttons*? With buttons, your markup could look like:

```
<button type="button" aria-label="Play">►</button>
<button type="button" aria-label="Pause">‖</button>
```

Comment: Maybe it is even better to have only one button whose aria-label value changes on click

Comment: @audre7: Maybe, yes. Relevant questions on UX: [Alternates to the “play/pause” button](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/9184/17023) · [Separation of play and pause buttons for playing media](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1215/17023) · [Should a toggle button show its current state or the state to which it will change?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1318/17023)

Comment: Changing the `aria-label` is a good solution. There are some caveats about the distinguishing the names from `aria-live` **announcements** about the change. Read [this useful article which addresses changing the accessible name of a toggle button.](https://inclusive-components.design/toggle-button/#changinglabels) It discusses play/pause buttons specifically.